# Examples of the use of Claudian letters (Ⅎ, Ↄ, Ⱶ)

Tags: classical-latin, alphabet, example-request

Emperor Claudius introduced three additional letters to the Latin alphabet: Ⅎ, Ↄ, and Ⱶ.

What are some examples of the words in which these letters were used?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudian_letters in all sorts of words. Are you looking for something more specific than what's written on Wikipedia?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see more examples, e.g., does the letter Ⱶ occur in other environments than the ending -umus/-imus?

Comment: I wonder whether this question might benefit from greater detail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last line of an AD 49 boundary stone uses the Ⅎ twice, representing the consonantal *v*:

[image]

The last line reads: *ampliaℲit terminaℲitq[ue]*.  ([*Illustrated Introduction to Latin Epigraphy*, 118](https://books.google.com/books?id=ywI6SDUggk4C&pg=PA118)).

According to John Wordsworth, a few other examples include:

> VOℲIMVS, ℲOℲEMVS, ARℲALES, ARℲALIVM [...] BOℲE, IOℲI [...] ℲELINA, ℲIR

As for the Ⱶ, its use is largely restricted to words of Greek origin, according to Revilo P. Oliver:

[image: Revilo P. Oliver, "The Claudian Letter Ⱶ," page 251]

He concludes:

[image: Revilo P. Oliver, "The Claudian Letter Ⱶ," page 256]

Examples of the use of the letter, according to John Worsdsworth, include:

> CⱵCNVS, BⱵBLIOTHECA, and once in GⱵBERNATOR

The remaining letter, Ↄ, has not been found in any published inscriptions, but based on the testimony of Priscian it was meant to represent the sound of *bs* and *ps*. (cf. Oliver and Wordsworth)

---

- [Revilo P. Oliver, "The Claudian Letter Ⱶ," *American Journal of Archaeology*, Vol. 53, No. 3 (Jul.–Sep., 1949), pp. 249–257.](https://www.jstor.org/stable/500662)
- John Worsworth, [*Fragments and specimens of early Latin*, 9](https://books.google.com/books?id=67wUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA9)