# Were there ever two "Y" forms in classical Greek or Latin?

Tags: alphabet

Looking through the fantastically-titled *Libro di M. Giovambattista Palatino cittadino romano : nelqual s'insegna à scriuer ogni sorte lettera, antica & moderna, di qualun que natione, con le sue regole, & misure, & essempi : et con vn breve et vtil discorso de le cifre* by Palatino, I notice that [double-page G (PDF-page 100)](https://archive.org/stream/librodimgiovamba00pala#page/n99/mode/2up) contains a spread of the Latin Alphabet ("ALPHABETVM LATINORVM"). There is something decidedly odd about the letter choice however — note that the bottom line contains two almost-identical "Y" forms.

[image: Double-page G, showing the Latin alphabet on the left and the Greek alphabet on the right. The Latin alphabet has the letters: A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Y Z. The second "Y" resembles a greek upsilon.]

Is there a historical reason for this? Were the letters pronounced differently?

---

Similarly, [double-page Eiiii (PDF-page 75)](https://archive.org/details/librodimgiovamba00pala/page/n73/mode/2up) of the same book contains a double-page spread of the Roman letters ("LETTERE ROMANE").  This also shows the two different forms of letter "Y".

[image: Double-page Eiiii, showing the Roman alphabet: A B C D E F G H I K L M N O P Q R S T V X Y Y Z. The second "Y" resembles a greek upsilon.]

Answer (score 7):

I think that the two forms of the letter Y given on that page are purely aesthetic variations of the same character. It also makes the letter array a neat 6 × 4 array, like the Greek one on the other page of the specimen book. Palatino was a typographer, after all.

However, for a short time in antiquity, there were two different forms of the Y, the Y as we know it and a "short Y" Ⱶ introduced be emperor Claudius and not continued after his reign, see [Examples of the use of Claudian letters (Ⅎ, Ↄ, Ⱶ)](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/271/examples-of-the-use-of-claudian-letters-%e2%84%b2-%e2%86%83-%e2%b1%b5)

Comment: Doubling a letter just to fill the array? Imho surely there were other ways or types for this...

Comment: (E.g. the Greek table on the opposite page has one letter less on the last row but looks neat.)

Comment: @Helen and on p. 72 a second "R" is used to fill the page beautifully.

Comment: And some other tables have some more random repeated letters, it looks like. Hm...

Answer (score 7):

I think jknappen is right: that extra Y isn't anything but a fancy Y. A few pages back (86/87), only one Y is mentioned.

There were two forms of the the Y in Greek, though. In fact, there were several. It's unfortunate that Lilian Jeffery's [*Local Scripts of Archaic Greece*](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&biw=1920&bih=930&tbm=bks&q=Jeffery+Local+Scripts+of+Archaic+Greece) doesn't return a preview, but you can see a succinct chart under Cook's [*Greek Inscriptions*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kp806ShRDh8C&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false).

[image: Epichoric Alphabet Scripts]

It wasn't until rather late that in its history that the Greek alphabet was standardized.

The variation in Y meant that the Romans borrowed the letter as V and then later reborrowed the letter, to represent the Greek vowel rather than their native one, as Y.

Not that this answers your specific query, but I mention it in case you stumble upon additional variations in the future.