# Is the B voiced in "abs"?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation

I recently came across [the Wiktionary page for *abstemius*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstemius) and I was genuinely surprised by the pronunciation guide.
It says that in classical Latin the B is the unvoiced /p/ instead of /b/.
Is this really the case?
I had always pronounced B as /b/ everywhere, including the simplest example *abs*.
Wiktionary is not particularly reliable and I couldn't find other sources to support or refute the unvoiced pronunciation, so I have to ask here.
Is the B in *abs* /p/ or /b/?

Comment: The [Claudian letters](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/271/examples-of-the-use-of-claudian-letters-Ⅎ-Ↄ-Ⱶ/454#454) may be relevant data on the pronunciation of "bs", although Ↄ apparently wasn't used in any real inscriptions, it was just proposed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, Wiktionary has it right – *b* is not voiced before *t* or *s*, as W. Sidney Allen explains ([*Vox Latina*, 21](https://books.google.com/books?id=aexkj_0oj3MC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21)):

> On general phonetic grounds it is highly probable that the *b* before *t* or *s* should stand for [p]. It is moreover expressly stated by Quintilian (i, 7, 7) and other grammarians, and clearly indicated by inscriptional spellings with p at all periods (e.g. *pleps, opsides, apsoluere, suptilissima, optinebit*). The distinction between spelling and speech is clearly summed up by Quintilian in the words: '*b* litteram ratio poscit, aures magis audiunt *p*'; and on the writing of *abs* Velius Longus comments (K. vii, 62): 'qui originem uerborum propriam respiciunt, per *b* scribunt'.

He explains that *b* is "partially assimilated to the following *t* or *s*" in words like *obsideo* and *urbs*, becoming the voiceless /p/ as a result, but that the written *b* is retained because of the parallels with *obeo* and *urbis*.  With respect to *abs* in particular, he writes:

> Similarly the preposition *abs* owes its writing with *b* rather than *p* to the alternative form *ab*.

So then, the *b* in *abs* is the voiceless /p/, not voiced /b/.

Comment: The is quite common. Another example would be the spelling *equus* for *ecus,* to maintain conformity with *equi, equo* et al., or *coquus* for *cocus.*