# "ejus" versus "eius"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Is there a difference between "ejus" and "eius?"

The context is two vulgate editions of Genesis 3:15 of the Bible.

The Clementine Vulgate has:

> Inimicitias ponam inter te et mulierem, et semen tuum et semen illius
> : ipsa conteret caput tuum, et tu insidiaberis calcaneo **ejus**.

The Stuttart edition of the vulgate has:

> inimicitias ponam inter te et mulierem et semen tuum et semen illius
> ipsa conteret caput tuum et tu insidiaberis calcaneo **eius**

Is this a typo? Does it affect the meaning of the text?

Comment: My intention is not to provide an answer per se, but rather [this interesting source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfB9mX5UUNU) on the letter "j" and its relation to "i" in the Latin language thoughout the centuries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In antiquity, there was no letter J in Latin alphabet. Letter I was used for both vowel /i/ and consonant /i̯/ (alternative notation: /j/).

[Letter J](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J#History) was invented in late Middle Ages.

Classical spelling of this pronoun is ⟨eius⟩.

Pronunciation in Classical Latin: /ˈei̯.i̯us/, [ˈɛi̯ːʊs̠]

Pronunciation in Ecclesiastical Latin: /ˈe.jus/, [ˈɛːjus]

Answer (score 10):

To add a bit more context:

The Latin alphabet is pretty well-suited for Latin, all things considered. It was adapted in antiquity to fit the phonology of the language, with new letters like G and Y invented or borrowed to better represent the sounds of Latin.

But, it's not quite perfect. There are a few contrasts in Latin that the Classical alphabet just didn't have a way to represent (at least not consistently). For example, the same letters were used for long vowels and short vowels: ALIVM with a short A means "another", but ALIVM with a long A means "garlic". Similarly, the same letters were used for vowels and semivowels: VOLVIT means "she wanted" if the second V is a vowel (approximately "woh-loo-it"), and "it rotates" if it's a semivowel (approximately "wohl-wit").

As a result, we tend to modify the alphabet in modern usage (and not just by introducing lowercase letters). For example, we can write *alium* versus *ālium*, and *voluit* versus *volvit*, and the ambiguity disappears. The Classical alphabet didn't have any distinction between I and J, or U and V, but nowadays it's common to use I and U for the vowels and J and V for the semivowels.

This is why I prefer the spelling *ejus*. The J represents a semivowel in this word, not a vowel. But, the spelling *eius* is closer to what the ancient Romans would have used, and some editors prefer it for that reason. Either way, it's representing the same Latin word, meaning "his/her/its". It doesn't change the meaning any more than switching from all-capitals to lowercase.

Comment: However, even when writers generally use U and V, they would apparently spell /su̯/ with SU, not SV. So there is still no consistency. Example: [suāvis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/suavis#Latin). Or do you actually spell it as *svavis* / *svāvis*?

Comment: @Arfrever It varies a lot by publisher; I used to even use _qv_ and _ngv_ for labiovelars in my notes but nobody else does that so I ended up dropping it.

Comment: @Arfrever: Note that su-, qu- and -gu- never ended up developing into clusters ending with [v] in Romance languages, and thus aren't pronounced with [v] in the Italian (or "Ecclesiastical") pronunciation of Latin. The pattern to the usual use of -V- and -U- is consistent; it just isn't as simple as "U is always syllabic, V is always non-syllabic." (Other systems [have been used in the past](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16277/9).)

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion of the J for consonantal “i” is helpful when scanning poetry but there is no change in pronunciation from eius and ejus. It is not a typo. Just two different ways to spell the same word. I prefer eius because the ancient Romans didn’t have the letter J.